# How to find elements in webview in android using appium

Tags: android-webview, appium, hybrid-mobile-app, android-testing, appium-android

I am new in automation testing . I am trying to find elements in webview in Android app using appium .
Below is code i am using but I am not able to find say **div** using its id

```
private AppiumDriver<WebElement> driver;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    // set up appium


}
@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    driver.quit();
}

@Test
public void webView() throws InterruptedException {

     DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
     capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","Android Emulator");

     capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.hokucampusaffairs");
     capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.mybeeps.DashboardActivity");
     try {
        driver = new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Thread.sleep(6000);
   Set<String> contextNames = driver.getContextHandles();
    for (String contextName : contextNames) {
      System.out.println(contextName);
      if (contextName.contains("WEBVIEW")){
        driver.context(contextName);
      }
    }
 String pagesource=   driver.getPageSource();
 String  url=   driver.getCurrentUrl();
 try {
    WebElement inputField = **driver.findElement(By.id("top-container"));**
    inputField.click();
 }
 catch(Exception e)
 {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }

}
```

Code in bold is not finding div using its id . Also findelementbyTag is only finding parent elements .

I am using latest version of appium /Android sdk/java 1.8

Comment: Exception :  no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"top-container"}

Answer (score 0):

Exception gives you the answer - no element found with `id='top-container'`

1. Make sure you switch driver to webview
2. Try other locator strategies, e.g. Xpath
3. For webview inspection you can use chrome dev tools: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/webviews